# How to monitor gcloud k8s HTTP failure rate?

Tags: kubernetes, gcloud, stackdriver, nginx-ingress

I'm working on a production **K8s** cluster with an HTTP-based application and I'd like to setup monitoring and alerting for HTTP errors. It's clear how to check the uptime of the service (using monitoring e.g. stackdriver), but absolutely not regarding HTTP failure rate.

I've got an `nginx-ingress-controller` as an end-point (with external load balancer).

How to collect and view the metrics such as latency, HTTP failures, etc. from this load balancer?

In particular I need to now, when **HTTP response failure rate** exceeds some percentage.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking at monitoring HTTP 4XX and 5XX errors for example I believe the best way is to aggregate the load balancer and the nginx ingress controller logs in some logging tool. If you are looking at open source solutions you could use something like [Elasticsearch](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch) with [Kibana](https://github.com/elastic/kibana) to visualize the errors over a time frame. To send the logs you can use a forwarder like [fluent-bit](https://fluentbit.io/) or [Fluentd](https://www.fluentd.org/).

If you have a budget for a paid tool you can use a commercially available solution like:

- [Loggly](https://www.loggly.com/)
- [Datadog logging](https://docs.datadoghq.com/logs/)
- [Papertrail](https://www.papertrail.com/)
- etc.

Then you can set up alerts with any of these tools. For Elasticsearch you can use something like [elastalert](https://github.com/Yelp/elastalert)

If you are using GCP you can also use their [Logging tool](https://cloud.google.com/logging), create a custom metric, and alert on that metric.

[image: Logging]

Another alternative, but may not have the metrics that you are looking for is to use [Prometheus](https://prometheus.io/) with an [Nginx ingress Prometheus exporter](https://github.com/nginxinc/nginx-prometheus-exporter) to monitor nginx metrics (it depends on what metrics you'd like to monitor)

Comment: If you are using Google Cloud platform you can try stackdriver monitoring, using alert policy: https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/alerts/concepts-indepth

Comment: @WilfredL., alert policy is okay, when you want to constantly ping your frontpage or backend healthcheck, but what if you want to collect ALL requests 4xx and 5xx errors?

Comment: Nice wrap up, Rico. What about gcloud built-in tools? Maybe Error reporting?
Yes, you're right I just want to monitor 4XX and 5XX

Comment: Added to the answer. Thanks!

Comment: @Rico, that looks interesting. How exactly can I get 4XX/5XX rate with that "Create Metric"?

Comment: using counter metrics https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/logs-based-metrics/counter-metrics and labeling it: https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/logs-based-metrics/labels you can use the `httpRequest.status` label